# Problema na impressão do código envolvendo strings (linguagem c)

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIAS 7

typedef struct {
   char nome[51];
   int idade;
   int refrigerante[7];
}Paciente;

int main() {   

   Paciente habitos;
   //Lendo os dados do paciente
   fgets(habitos.nome,51,stdin);
   scanf("%d", &habitos.idade);
   for (int i = 0; i < DIAS; i++) {
     scanf("%d", &habitos.refrigerante[i]);
   }
int k; //constante
scanf("%d", &k);

int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < DIAS; i++) {
    if (habitos.refrigerante[i] > k) {
        x++;
    }
}

   printf("%s toma mais que %d refrigerantes %d vezes por semana", habitos.nome, k, x);

return 0;
}
```

Gostaria que o código fosse impresso em uma única linha. No entanto, após a execução da string, o código salta uma linha e imprime o restante do texto. Aonde se encontra o erro?

Comment: `fgets()` vai ler o `'\n'` da string, a menos que tenha exatos 51 bytes na entrada. Teste o último byte e se for `'\n'` troque por zero. Poste um programa inteiro aqui, compilável, DENTRO da caixa de código :) TESTE sempre o retorno de `scanf()`. Qual o propósito de seguir no loop se não conseguiu ler a idade, por exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

faz isso logo após chamar o fgets:

```
if(habitos.nome[strlen(habitos.nome)-1] == '\n')
    habitos.nome[strlen(habitos.nome)-1] = 0;
```

o fgets adiciona newline character ao fim da string, dai vc precisa retirá-lo.